# How to move a UIScrollView's x and y position? (Not talking about the contents of the scroller but the scroller itself)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to programmatically move a scrollview's x and y position but idk how.

I tried this-

```
_scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,-30);
```

Comment: This is really hard to understand. What is a "scroller"?. Either explain this in a different way or draw us a picture or something perhaps.

Comment: Just set frame of scrollView like,
_scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-30, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);

And delete this question if you understood the solution. If you are new to iOS development please try to read developer docs before putting any questions here.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: I did that, except it would mess up all the other images I put on it

Comment: @Dima

By scroller I'm talking about a UIScrollView instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really intended as a comment, but I don't have enough rep to comment..

Your question is hard to understand, but I think what you are asking is can you move the actual UIScrollView..?

If so, try setting the frame of the scrollView to where you want.

So assuming that you have a IBOutlet property to your UIScrollView try something like

```
CGRect oldFrame = self.scroller.frame;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x,oldFrame.origin.y - 30,oldFrame.size.width,oldFrame.size.height);

[self.scroller setFrame:newFrame];
```

Comment: Wow, this worked without messing up my images. I tried doing this except with setFrame:CGRectMake... instead of creating a CGRect variable. Maybe that's what caused my files to bug out? Thanks kind stranger! :)